# Addind image tooltip to treeview nodes in C#.new windows application

Tags: c#-4.0

i have treeview windows application how can i add image tooltip to treenode ..
any one pls help me ..
Addind image tooltip to treeview nodes in C#.new windows application
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, you should go with custom tooltip control that supports desired image and tooltip text in it.